# Curl FTP connection pooling

Tags: curl, ftp

In my application I am executing curl.exe as external command to get list of files from an FTP folder. I need to scan multiple folders to the list so I am calling this command multiple times output the file listing into local directory.

> curl ftp://my-ip:port/path/1234/ --user username:password --list-only
>   -o C:\localfolder\1234.txt
>
> curl ftp://my-ip:port/path/8910/ --user username:password --list-only
>   -o C:\localfolder\8910.txt

So I will have 1 file per each directory. We can't use wild card pattern for listing files from all required directories as they have no pattern, just random integer numbers.

Most of the cases I will need to scan 200 directors but also in some cases a couple of thousands upto 9000 (which is maximum).  I have no problem for it as it is working perfect without any issues. Except in some extreme cases I won't get list from 1 or 2 directories due to network glitch.

Now I am thinking of optimization. Two optimizations can be done here

My application level optimization: Instead of calling curl.exe so many times, I will create a dynamic bat file with multiple calls in it so my application will call it only once and batch file will have the actual curl calls.

**Curl connection pooling:** This is what I am looking if it is possible with curl.exe I read somewhere sometime ago that curl library has connection pooling support like in PHP but I am not sure if curl executable has that capability. It could be good performance improvement if I can utilize this feature if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the cURL manual (in the section called *PERSISTENT CONNECTIONS*):

> Specifying multiple files on a single command line will make curl transfer
>     all of them, one after the other in the specified order.
>
> libcurl will attempt to use persistent connections for the transfers so that
>     the second transfer to the same host can use the same connection that was
>     already initiated and was left open in the previous transfer. This greatly
>     decreases connection time for all but the first transfer and it makes a far
>     better use of the network.

Source: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Something like

```
curl --user username:password --list-only ftp://my-ip:port/path/1234/ -o C:\localfolder\1234.txt ftp://my-ip:port/path/8910/ -o C:\localfolder\8910.txt
```

should do what you are looking for (for 2 or more URLs).